# Getting Last Element of Array In Handlebars by Length -1

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to get the last element of an array in handlebars. I was thinking that I could just do:

```
{{#each names}}
     <p>{{ this.[this.length -1] }}</p>
{{/each }}
```

But that doesn't work. I get nothing.

How can I do this?